# How to get and manipulate text between two special charters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

```
Hi *John* We wish you* Happy Birthday * and blah blah blah..
```

Ho can I get text between each pair of * and return like

```
Hi <b>john</b> We wish you <b> Happy Birthday </b> and blah blah blah..
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regexp `/\*([^\*]+)\*/g`

```js
const regex = /\*([^\*]+)\*/g;
const str = `Hi *John* We wish you* Happy Birthday * and blah blah blah..`;
const subst = `<b>$1</b>`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

**As a function**

```js
const str = `Hi *John* We wish you* Happy Birthday * and blah blah blah..`;
function bold(str) {
 const regex = /\*([^\*]+)\*/g;
 const subst = `<b>$1</b>`;
 // The substituted value will be contained in the returned variable
 return str.replace(regex, subst);
}
const result = bold(str);
console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: with this regexp, how to replace start and end tag

Comment: It is working good, Is it possible to create angular filter for this

Comment: You need this to be a function?

Comment: Yes, custom filter function

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem.

```js
str = "Hi *John* We wish you* Happy Birthday * and blah blah blah..";

replaceInStr(str, "<b>");

function replaceInStr(str, replace) {
    str = str.replace(/\*/, replace);
    if(replace === "<b>") {
      replace = "</b>";
    } else {
     replace = "<b>";
    }
    
    if(str.search(/\*/) !== -1) {
     replaceInStr(str, replace);
    } else {
     console.log(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working good, Is it possible to create angular filter for this

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this

```
    var stringArray = str.split("*");
    var stringOut = "";

    for (var i = 0 ; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
        stringOut += stringArray[i];
        if (i % 2 !== 0) {
            stringOut += "</br>";
        }
        else
        {
            stringOut += "<br>";
        }

    }
```

Comment: But that won't create closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var txt = "Hi *John* We wish you* Happy Birthday * and blah blah blah.."; 

txt = txt.replace(/\*(.*?)\*/g, "<b>$1</b>");
console.log(txt);
```